# is it ever useful to define a class method with a reference to self not called 'self' in Python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm teaching myself Python and I see the following in [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) [section 5.3](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html):

> By convention, the first argument of any Python class method (the reference to the current instance) is called `self`. This argument fills the role of the reserved word `this` in C++ or Java, but `self` is not a reserved word in Python, merely a naming convention. Nonetheless, please don't call it anything but `self`; this is a very strong convention.

Considering that `self` is *not* a Python keyword, I'm guessing that it can sometimes be useful to use something else.  Are there any such cases?  If not, why is it *not* a keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only case of this I've seen is when you define a function outside of a class definition, and then assign it to the class, e.g.:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        # Do something with 'self'

def baz(inst):
    return inst.bar()

Foo.baz = baz
```

In this case, `self` is a little strange to use, because the function could be applied to many classes. Most often I've seen `inst` or `cls` used instead.

Comment: Weird, but in this case, seems reasonable not to use self.

Answer (score 9):

No, unless you want to confuse every other programmer that looks at your code after you write it.  `self` is not a keyword because it is an identifier.  It *could* have been a keyword and the fact that it isn't one was a design decision.

Comment: If you're using `@classmethod`, however, the first argument isn't `self`, it's often `cls`.

Comment: That is true but that is simply another convention.  I should have been more clear that the convention of using `self` applies to instance methods.

Answer (score 5):

As a side observation, note that Pilgrim is committing a common misuse of terms here: a *class method* is quite a different thing from an *instance method*, which is what he's talking about here. As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_science)) puts it, "a method is a subroutine that is exclusively associated either with a class (in which case it is called a class method or a static method) or with an object (in which case it is an instance method).". Python's built-ins include a `staticmethod` type, to make static methods, and a `classmethod` type, to make class methods, each generally used as a decorator; if you don't use either, a `def` in a class body makes an instance method. E.g.:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def noclass(self): print self
...   @classmethod
...   def withclass(cls): print cls
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> x.noclass()
<__main__.X object at 0x698d0>
>>> x.withclass()
<class '__main__.X'>
>>>
```

As you see, the instance method `noclass` gets the instance as its argument, but the class method `withclass` gets the class instead.

So it would be **extremely** confusing and misleading to use `self` as the name of the first parameter of a class method: the convention in this case is instead to use `cls`, as in my example above. While this IS just a convention, there is no real good reason for violating it -- any more than there would be, say, for naming a variable `number_of_cats` if the purpose of the variable is counting dogs!-)

Comment: "...note that Pilgrim is committing a common misuse of terms here: a class method is...": well, it depends on how you listen to his phrase "any Python class method." Is it "Python-class method" or "Python class-method"? You're taking the latter interpretation. If he'd said, "the first argument of any method of a Python class's instance method", he would have been perfectly clear if somewhat verbose.

Comment: @hughdbrown: Or he could have said "the first argument of any instance method", which would imply that the method is a method of a class without having to state it.

Comment: @cat, yup. @hughdbrown, even in the kindest interpretation, "any method of a Python class" at least _includes_ classmethods (who could argue that classmethods aren't methods of a class?!) so the sentence is still wrong. Mark is a friend and a colleague, and I love his work, but it's nevertheless clear that he (and my wife Anna, who was his tech editor for the book) had a small howler here!-)

Answer (score 2):

I once had some code like (and I apologize for lack of creativity in the example):

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, volume=1):
        self.volume = volume
        self.description = "Animal"

    def Sound(self):
        pass

    def GetADog(self, newvolume):
        class Dog(Animal):
            def Sound(this):
                return self.description + ": " + ("woof" * this.volume)
        return Dog(newvolume)
```

Then we have output like:

```
>>> a = Animal(3)
>>> d = a.GetADog(2)
>>> d.Sound()
'Animal: woofwoof'
```

I wasn't sure if `self` within the `Dog` class would shadow `self` within the `Animal` class, so I opted to make `Dog`'s reference the word "this" instead.  In my opinion and for that particular application, that was more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main reason `self` is used by convention rather than being a Python keyword is because it's simpler to have all methods/functions take arguments the same way rather than having to put together different argument forms for functions, class methods, instance methods, etc.

Note that if you have an *actual* class method (i.e. one defined using the `classmethod` decorator), the convention is to use "cls" instead of "self".

Comment: That would be because you're no longer referring to an object instance but a class. (i.e. two different things)

Comment: @michaelmior: While your first sentence is correct, the second is technically incorrect. Classes are first-class objects in Python, and can be manipulated just as other object instances can.

Comment: (Not that it makes much of a difference for methods contained inside a class.)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a convention, not language syntax. There is a [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that people who program in Python follow. This way libraries have a familiar look and feel. Python places a lot of emphasis on readability, and consistency is an important part of this.